# How to filter a large csv file with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, filter, dataset

I have [this](https://gofile.io/d/T3RYLb) csv file but I need to filter only the data I need with Python 3.

In short, that csv represents many aggregate covid19 data. But I only need some parts of it. I need for all the time period, only the number of new deaths per million people in Italy, Sweden, Germany and France, and no more.

Then, I want to create another CSV given this intestation:

> date,italy,sweden,germany,france

(E.g, 01-Apr-2020,13.35,4.52,1.22,6.74)

My code is the following:

```
    cases_by_day = dict()
location = {'Italy': 0.0, 'Sweden': 0.0, 'France': 0.0, 'Germany': 0.0}

with open("data.csv") as f:
    v = f.readlines()
    for line in v:
        elements = line.split(",")
        # print(elements)
        date = datetime.strptime(elements[3], "%Y-%m-%d")
        cases_by_day[str(elements[3])] = location

with open("data.csv") as h:
    for line in h:
        a = line.split(",")
        if "Italy" in a[2]:
            u = str(a[3])
            if len(a[15]) == 0:
                cases_by_day[u]["Italy"] = 0.0
            else:
                # print(float(a[15]))
                # print(u)
                cases_by_day[u]["Italy"] = float(a[15])
            # print(cases_by_day[u]["Italy"])
        elif "Sweden" in a[2]:
            i = str(a[3])
            if len(a[15]) == 0:
                cases_by_day[i]["Sweden"] = 0.0
            else:
                cases_by_day[i]["Sweden"] = float(a[15])
        elif "France" in a[2]:
            o = str(a[3])
            if len(a[15]) == 0:
                cases_by_day[o]["France"] = 0.0
            else:
                cases_by_day[o]["France"] = float(a[15])
        elif "Germany" in a[2]:
            p = str(a[3])
            if len(a[15]) == 0:
                cases_by_day[p]["Germany"] = 0.0
            else:
                cases_by_day.get(p)["Germany"] = float(a[15])

print(cases_by_day)
```

However, at the end of the process every date key has the same nested dict associated and I don't know why

Edit: The intestation of data.csv is the following:

iso_code,
continent,
location,
date,
total_cases,
new_cases,
new_cases_smoothed,
total_deaths,
new_deaths,
new_deaths_smoothed,
total_cases_per_million,
new_cases_per_million,
new_cases_smoothed_per_million,
total_deaths_per_million,
new_deaths_per_million,
new_deaths_smoothed_per_million, 16
reproduction_rate,
icu_patients,
icu_patients_per_million,
hosp_patients,
hosp_patients_per_million,
weekly_icu_admissions,
weekly_icu_admissions_per_million,
weekly_hosp_admissions,
weekly_hosp_admissions_per_million,
total_tests,
new_tests,
total_tests_per_thousand,
new_tests_per_thousand,
new_tests_smoothed,
new_tests_smoothed_per_thousand,
positive_rate,
tests_per_case,
tests_units,
stringency_index,
population,
population_density,
median_age,
aged_65_older,
aged_70_older,
gdp_per_capita,
extreme_poverty,
cardiovasc_death_rate,
diabetes_prevalence,
female_smokers,
male_smokers,
handwashing_facilities,
hospital_beds_per_thousand,
life_expectancy,
human_development_index

The column of my interest are 2,3 and 15 (counting from zero).
But there are data from other countries that I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it works with the following code edit (only significant part)

```
italy = dict()
sweden= dict()
germany= dict()
france = dict()
cases_by_day = dict()

with open("data.csv") as f:
    v = f.readlines()
    for line in v:
        elements = line.split(",")
        # print(elements)
        date = datetime.strptime(elements[3], "%Y-%m-%d")
        italy[str(elements[3])] = 0.0
        sweden[str(elements[3])] = 0.0
        germany[str(elements[3])] = 0.0
        france[str(elements[3])] = 0.0

with open("data.csv") as h:
    for line in h:
        a = line.split(",")
        if "Italy" in a[2]:
            u = str(a[3])
            if len(a[15]) == 0:
                italy[u] = float(0.0)
            else:
                # print(cases_by_day[u]["Italy"])
                # print(u)
                italy[u] = float(a[15])
            # print(cases_by_day[u]["Italy"])
        elif "Sweden" in a[2]:
            i = str(a[3])
            if len(a[15]) == 0:
                sweden[i] = 0.0
            else:
                sweden[i] = float(a[15])
        elif "France" in a[2]:
            o = str(a[3])
            if len(a[15]) == 0:
                france[o] = 0.0
            else:
                france[o] = float(a[15])
        elif "Germany" in a[2]:
            p = str(a[3])
            if len(a[15]) == 0:
                germany[p] = 0.0
            else:
                germany[p] = float(a[15])
```

So I basically splitted my dicts.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are only creating one copy of the "nested" part of your dictionary and then pointing to **the same instance** in all cases in your `cases_by_day` dictionary.  So you just have multiple copies (references) to the same thing.  This is the problem line:

```
cases_by_day[str(elements[3])] = location
```

I would suggest a couple things.  If you want to preserve the format you have of data[day][country] and have representations of the "zeros" then just make a new (empty) dictionary every time you find a new date on the fly.  Then you only have to read the file once.  You're pretty close.

Depending on what you want to do with the data, the `pandas` solution may be helpful, if you want to get to dictionaries, keep at it w/ the fixes above and comment back if you are stuck!

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the module pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
cols =[' continent', ' location', ' new_deaths_per_million']
subset = ['list of countries needed']
dff = df.loc[df[' location'].isin(subset)]
dff[cols].to_csv('nameofyourfile.csv)
```

Comment: I've edited adding the intestation of my csv in order to specify better

Comment: updated answer, your column headers have an extra blank space at the front fyi

Comment: I checked the updated answer but the format is not what I wanted:

e.g 01-Apr-2020,13.35,4.52,1.22,6.74

One line of the generated csv is : 18592,2020-01-29,France,0.0

Comment: cols = [' date', ' location', ' new_deaths_per_million']. cols is the list of columns you are looking for ordered left to right. I might have skimmed the top a little too fast I just gave columns 2,3,15 from 1.

Comment: I've already changed the column names, the output is always wrong.

Comment: It's hard for me to help you without having the dataset. I grabbed those columns, put them into a data frame and filtered them to get the columns and countries. If location has the names of the countries that should filter them. Im a little confused at what you want. Are you trying to transpose location?